# PHP dynamic bind , how to know how many results are selected from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using a dynamic bind_parm , which is:

```
public function get_result($sql,$types = null,$params = null) {
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);

if($types&&$params)
{
    $bind_names[] = $types;
    for ($i=0; $i<count($params);$i++) 
    {
        $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
        $$bind_name = $params[$i];
        $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
    }
    $return = call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$bind_names);
}

$stmt->execute();

# these lines of code below return one dimentional array, similar to mysqli::fetch_assoc()
$meta = $stmt->result_metadata(); 

while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) { 
    $var = $field->name; 
    $$var = null; 
    $parameters[$field->name] = &$$var; 
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters); 

while($stmt->fetch()) 
{ 
    $this->handler ($parameters); // Handle queried results
}

$stmt->close();
```

}

However , i'm unable to retrieve that how many rows were selected during last operation ,  i tried $mysqli->affected_rows , which's always -1; And $mysqli->num_rows was inaccessible , it was undefined in $mysqli.

I think putting an variable inside that loop to count it is unnecessary , does anyone have a suggestion ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()');
$stmt->execute();
$rowsCount = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
```